# Is it possible to repeat modified Shape Key actions?

Tags: animation, shape-keys, fcurves

so I'm trying to sync a Taurus mesh with some music to mimic the thumping of a bass and have found this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RWebgsyuaNg (starts around 1:20) which describes using the shape key mixed with a Sine wave modifier that restricts the keyframes I'm using so I can isolate my "wub wub"'s to when the song does the same.

There's a few issues with me doing it this way. For each set of "Wubbles", as we'll call them, I have to add a new modifier (and restrict keyframes) each time.

[image]

Now this wouldn't be a huge issue, but I'd like to copy all of this data and repeat its usage when the song itself repeats, but I can't seem to select the Sine wave to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> it and move it down the frame line. Is there a way to do this? or am I just missing the easier way of animating my Taurus altogether?

Comment: Have you considered using the NLA editor? eg, have one wub_wub action starting at frame 1, then use the NLA to position in your timeline.

Comment: I have not, I'll check it out and see if that'll work better for me :) thanks for the insight.

Comment: As an alternative to the NLA Editor, you should also be able to bake those curves. If you post your .blend maybe we can take a look and see why it can't be selected too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blender includes the ability to convert sampled [f-curves to keyframes](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.FCurve.html#bpy.types.FCurve.convert_to_keyframes), but doesn't include a way to use it without a python script. Luckily someone already has made an addon to make it easily accessible. Save a copy of [this addon](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/qwenger/BAddons/master/GraphEditor_ConvertFCurves/graph_editor_convert_fcurves.py) then [install and enable it](https://www.blender.org/manual/advanced/scripting/python/add_ons.html#installation-of-a-3rd-party-add-on).

Now you can bake the f-curve with <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>, delete the sine wave modifier and convert to keyframes with *Channel->Convert to->Keyframes from Samples*.

Now that you have a f-curve made of keyframes, you can delete any parts you don't need and duplicate the remaining as many times as you want.

With a graph editor and VSE open with a waveform displayed you can change the current frame by clicking in the VSE so that it is at the start of a "wubble" and this will also be visible in the graph editor, then use <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> and move into position visually.

[image: Sample editing layout]

Comment: Awesome, I'll have to check this out and give it a go. this sounds like exactly what I need to be accurate and specific with my f-curves. thank you VERY much!

Answer (score 1):

**Using the [NLA](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/nla.html).**

The [NLA](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/nla.html) is used to position,  repeat, scale (etc) actions as strips in tracks.  The fcurve modifiers can be retained and tweaked etc enabling you to keep one "master action".  Moving and positioning the strips is simple as is scaling their time and repeating.

Note For convenience I've added the action (Wubble.001) to Cube.001 to show it in graph editor, as it gets confusing having both an action and NLA tracks / strips on same object.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for going through the extra work to give me more feedback on this batFINGER :)